# Estimation of mean, variance, proportion for cakes baking in 30 ± 2 minutes, or estimation of parameters of a law for a distribution: is it the same?

Tags: distributions, variance, estimation, mean

I'm a beginner in statistics and I'm trying to figure things to ensure that I can consider parameters the same manner in two cases :

I believe that if we have enlighten a distribution with the knowledge of its law and the values of its parameters, then we have "won". Because we can predict the values we are inclined to receive from it.

We try to estimate the parameters of the underlying law of our distribution from a sample, and these parameters become the values of our $\mu$, $\sigma$, $\lambda$, degree of freedom...

But there also the mean, variance, proportion that are parameters commonly calculated from a sample, with an confidence interval accompanying them in problems like "*the cakes taking 30 ± 2 minutes to bake*".

May I consider that whatever my parameters have for goal :

- the explanation of a distribution, by the "*instantiation*" of its law,
- or get a range of values for a mean, variance or proportion, with a confidence interval

they are of the same kind, have to be considered the same manner,
or is there a trap, and special care must be taken when considering them for one of these purposes?

Comment: This question is far too general and vague to be answerable within our site guidelines.  If you have a specific statistical problem, then please describe it and we can try to help.